# Check if string begins with substring give wrong output

Tags: python, startswith

I'm trying to match only the strings that begins with `%%ABC XYZ:` or `%%RLMI UUEW:`, but I don't know why I'm getting true
in `Out[1]` when I use `startswith()` with a tuple and the string actually doesn't have the `%%` at the beginning.

```
'ABC XYZ:0882-928'.startswith(('%%RLMI UUEW:','%%ABC XYZ:'))
Out[1]: True

'%%ABC XYZ:0882-928'.startswith(('%%RLMI UUEW:','%%ABC XYZ:'))
Out[2]: True
```

When `startswith()` is used with a single sub string, the output is correct. Why? thanks in advance.

```
'ABC XYZ:7281-001'.startswith('%%ABC XYZ:')
Out[3]: False

'%%ABC XYZ:7281-001'.startswith('%%ABC XYZ:')
Out[4]: True
```

**UPDATE**

```
import sys

print("User Current Version:-", sys.version)
User Current Version:- 3.9.13 (main, Aug 25 2022, 23:51:50) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Your first example returns `False` for me using Python3.10 and Python2.7

Comment: @IainShelvington.  Ditto here with Python 3.8.10 and 2.7.18.

Comment: @IainShelvington Is python 3.9.13. See update in my original post.

Comment: I am using Linux.  Maybe it's a bug confined to the Windows version?

Comment: I suspect you installed or configured something weird that's doing this.

Comment: You appear to be using IPython, or something with a similar interface. Does the problem reproduce in a plain Python interactive session? What about if you launch Python as `python -I` to turn on isolated mode?

Comment: I'm trying within console of Spyder from Anaconda. When I run `python -I` in Anaconda prompt the output is correct. So the issue it seems to be with the spyder console. Thanks so much for your help.